# Getting command line output in VBScript (without writing to files)

Tags: windows, vbscript, subst, drive-mapping

I'm using VBScript, and my goal is to be able to substitute a drive letter for a path of my choosing.  I need the D drive, and if it's not available I need to check if it's already mapped to the right spot; then notify the user if it's not.  I found this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156605.aspx and I'm trying to adapt their second example:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec("cmd /c ping -n 3 -w 1000 157.59.0.1")
Do While Not objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    strText = objExecObject.StdOut.ReadLine()
    If Instr(strText, "Reply") > 0 Then
        Wscript.Echo "Reply received."
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

(my adaptations):

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec("cmd /c substr")
strText = ""

Do While Not objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    strText = strText & objExecObject.StdOut.ReadLine()
Loop

Wscript.Echo strText
```

Then I'll probably search for the string that tells where the D drive is mapped.  I've also tried `objShell.Exec("subst")`, but I still don't get any output.  Does anyone have any ideas on what I  might be doing wrong?  Or is there a better way to tell about drive mappings?  Thanks,

213897

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script doesn't work because you've mistyped the command name - it's `subst`, not `substr`.

Comment: wow, that's quite the thing to be missing for a couple of days... thanks for your help :)