# Display data from cmd into textbox VB6

Tags: vba, vb6

How can I insert data directly from cmd into text1? I tried this but get wrong output just some numbers...

```
Dim com As String
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim sCommand As String
sCommand = "dir"
Text1.Text = Shell("cmd.exe /k" & sCommand)
End Sub
```

Comment: `Shell` returns a status code, not the output of the command. Use [WshShell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8906912/3484251) instead. Also it couldn't have worked anyway, you need a space after `/k`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very close.  Check out this answer and it should point you in the right direction. [Getting command line output in VBScript (without writing to files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393345/getting-command-line-output-in-vbscript-without-writing-to-files) Basically you need to get the Shell command in to an object i.e objShell and then use the .StdOut.ReadLine() method.

Comment: The cmd parameter /k will prevent the anything from being returned to the caller. Nothing is returned until the window is closed. If the OP uses the /c switch as in the answer you referenced the OP will get the results they probably expect.