# pass multiple commands for cmd to execute as one block

Tags: vbscript

I created a very simple script for exercising purposes. I simply try to output the result of my command `myshell.run "tasklist | find 'cmd.exe'"`. But it fails with an error message. The error message is german 'Anweisungsende erwartet' in english it should mean 'statement completion expected'

```
set myshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

myvar = ""
myvar = myshell.run "tasklist | find 'cmd.exe'"


MsgBox "Output = " & myvar
```

I expect output like this:
`cmd.exe    5076 Console           1       3.156 K`

**Update:**

I tried it again with the information on the link of the possible duplicate.
I have to use `Exec` instead of `Run`

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec("cmd /C tasklist | find 'cmd.exe'")
strText = ""

Do While Not objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    strText = strText & objExecObject.StdOut.ReadLine()
Loop

Wscript.Echo strText
```

**Result**: No output, even though the cmd.exe is running. I think it is not possible to execute it if there is a pipe symbol. If i use only `cmd /C tasklist` then it outputs all the tasks.

Comment: [Add the parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5413977/11683).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I replaced the run command with this:
`myvar = myshell.run ("tasklist | find 'cmd.exe'")` but i always get the output `Output = 0`, regardless of whether `cmd.exe` is running or not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting command line output in VBScript (without writing to files)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393345/getting-command-line-output-in-vbscript-without-writing-to-files)

Comment: How is this a duplicate?

Comment: It shows you how to grab the output of a command. `Run` simply [returns a status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). Please use documentation instead of guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass multiple commands for `cmd` to execute as one block, you need to put quotes around them.
You must also respect [quote escaping rules](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/twistylittlepassagesallalike/archive/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-arguments-the-wrong-way.aspx) that one must use for CMD, because one of your block commands, `find`, also uses quotes.
And finally, you must remember to escape the resulting CMD-escaped quotes according to the language rules (VBScript).

In the end you should have:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec("cmd /C ""tasklist | find ^""cmd.exe^""""")
strText = ""

Do Until objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    strText = strText & objExecObject.StdOut.ReadLine()
Loop

Wscript.Echo strText
```

As a debugging hint, when you don't get a result from `StdOut`, you should also check `StdErr` in the same way.

Comment: Hint for others:
`When cmd transforms a command line and sees a ^, it ignores the ^ character itself and copies the next character to the new command line literally`

Comment: Note: The `^` are totally unneccessary, you can also just use `objShell.Exec("cmd /C ""tasklist | find ""cmd.exe""""")`